# How to trigger multiple TextBoxes to clear on button click in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a few Textboxes stacked, and a button that I'm trying to use to clear them all at once, triggered by a button click. What is the most simple way to handle this?

```xml
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="RefNum"/>
    <TextBox Name="CxName"/>
    <TextBox Name="ContInfo"/>
    <TextBox Name="CardInfo"/>
    <TextBox Name="Trans"/>
    <TextBox Name="Reason"/>
</Grid>
```

```xml
<Grid x:Name="RefGrid">
<Button Name="clearButton"/>
</Grid>
```

I tried using the Click="Name.Text = String.Empty" to no avail. The vb syntax is kinda new to me

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you're trying to clear the text property of the controls?

Comment: I don't think this would typically be done in the XAML.  I think the "WPF" way to do this is bind a command to the button which would clear the backing properties (you do have bound properties for the text, right?).

Comment: @Rufus I removed the Click="" action from the Button, as I explained it wasn't working

Comment: You can't just put code in the Click attribute.  If you're trying to do it that way, it has to just be the name of an event handler in the code-behind.

Comment: Also... which language is it?  VB or C#?  That does influence some nuance in the answers (e.g. `Option Strict` in VB and the option to set handlers using `Handles` instead of in the XAML).

Comment: @Craig I'm using a MainWindow.xaml with a Mainwindow.xaml.vb

Comment: May I know if there are updates about the question? Does the answer helps?

Answer (score 0):

@Vadim Martynov -s answer is a good possibility to make it work, but I would use:

```
TextBoxName.Clear();
```

instead of

```
TextBoxName.Text = "";
```

Comment: Oh thanks setting Text property can break an existing binding so Clear is a better way and I'll fix my answer.